# how to insert many rows without using loop from server side

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have a users table and notifications table

I want to insert notification for each user with the role **(admin)**

how can I do this using SQL commands? without looping and the **(insert)** commands from the server side

```
 SELECT id.users FROM users
 , (
INSERT INTO `notifications` (`id`, `note`, `link`, `type`, `object_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `status_2`, `user`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '', '', '', '', id.user , '', '', '', '');

)

WHERE user_role.users = "admin"
```

ps: I'm using CodeIgniter

I tried this but the syntax is wrong

Comment: well if are doing like this than you are doing it wrong just create another table for notification and it there is any notification for admin just show it, it can be like this `id|notification-bla|type|admin-id` now type can be admin, regular etc,

Comment: What's wrong with `insert into notifications select (NULL, '', '', '', '', id.user , '', '', '', '') from users where user_role.users = 'admin'`?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data scroll down to batch insert. This will give you better idea

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->insert_batch()
```

Generates an insert string based on the data you supply, and runs the query. You can either pass an array or an object to the function. Here is an example using an array:

```
$data = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
        )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'),  ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

And for large array or batch you can split your data into chunks like below:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($data, 500);

foreach ($chunks as $key => $chunk) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('table', $chunk);
}
```

Comment: bravo!, that will certainly work but what if users are like 20,000?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя You can use array_chunk($data, 500); for large batch.

Comment: so ultimately kind of loop through? :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create an insert statement combined with a select statement from your table (you are pretty close - but the syntax is wrong) - try the following

```
$this->db->query("
    INSERT INTO `notifications` (`note`, `link`, `type`, `object_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `status_2`, `user`, `date`)
    SELECT '' AS note, '' AS link, '' AS type, '' AS object_id, id, '' AS status, '' AS status_2, '' AS user, '' AS date  FROM users WHERE user_role.users = 'admin'
");
```

I assumed your `id` field in your notifications table is an auto increment - so i left that out.